# Google sheets, adding a value to a cell based on the contents of another

Tags: excel, dynamic, google-sheets, formula, addition

This may be delving in to scripting territory rather than formula, but I was wondering if it's possible to use google sheets to add values to a cell based on the contents of another? For example, If I had a sheet arranged like the following:

Column A|Column B|Column C|Column D
Apples      Oranges   Grapes
Tomatoes   Grapes    Oranges
Melons         Apples      Tomatoes
Grapes       Lemons     Apples

And then I had another section that had

Column G|Column H
Apples              1
Tomates           2
Oranges           3
Grapes             4
Melons              5
Lemons             6

Is there a formula that will let me populate the contents of column D by reading columns A - C on each row and adding the values set on column H? Making Column D read something like 8, 9, 8 etc?

I hope this question makes sense, thanks and apologies for the shoddy formatting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:C2,G:H,2,0)))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

For [google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets)

Please try this single-formula solution:

`=mmult(filter(VLOOKUP(A:C,G:H,2,0),A:A<>""),ArrayFormula(transpose(sign(column(A:C)))))`

Paste it in D1.

---

Here's a [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VY157ykKsCVDqEKDBp3oAVaG0LTXAz8wUCggCrFXMDM/edit#gid=138972300) of `sum` with arrayFormula.